# Is there a way to perform a cast or withColumn dataframe operation in PySpark without breaking a function chain?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Something I enjoy about working with `DataFrames` is the ability to chain function calls together.  The problem that I run into is that I'm struggling to find syntax that allows you to perform a `cast` or a `withColumn` operation that references  a column of the `DataFrame`.  For example:

```
counts = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv") \
    .options(header=True) \
    .load(path) \
    .filter("cast(filterColumn as int) in (8, 11, 12)") \
    .withColumn('newColumn',df.oldColumn.cast("date")) \  #<-- df doesn't exist, silly!
    .groupBy(df.newColumn) \
    .count() \
    .collect()
```

The interesting thing to note is that performing the cast works great in the `filter` call.  Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that either `withColumn` or `groupBy` support that kind of string api.  I have tried to do

```
.withColumn('newColumn','cast(oldColumn as date)')
```

but only get yelled at for not having passed in an instance of `column`:

```
assert isinstance(col, Column), "col should be Column"
```

which is the exact same problem i run into when trying to do the same thing with `groupBy`

Do I simply need to bite the bullet and break them up?

```
df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv") \
    .options(header=True) \
    .load(path) \
    .filter("cast(filterColumn as int) in (8, 11, 12)")

counts = df.withColumn('newColumn',df.oldColumn.cast("date"))
    .groupBy(df.newColumn) \
    .count() \
    .collect()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `col` function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

...
    .withColumn('newColumn', col('oldColumn').cast('date'))
```

or `expr`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

...
    .withColumn('newColumn', expr('cast(oldColumn as date)'))
```